# getting error clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Hi all I am getting this error while using an ocr cocoa pod. In Xcode

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

It works fine in simulator but as soon as I set it to external device i get this error.

I have tried disabling bitcode, cleaning the project, uninstalling and reinstalling the pods, and various other things listed on stack overflow.

has anybody else have any other ideas.

All the best

Tony

Comment: Have you tried to remove the application from you phone and then reinstalled it?

Comment: Hi @RashwanL I hadn't but have now same result. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Post the complete error, also check the build phases if the framework is added. And in the relevant framework is the target set ?

Comment: Fixed this issue, Even though i had set bitcode to NO on 5 different occasions i looked at the error and it said it was bitcode, I tried again and this time it worked.  Thanks for all your help....

Comment: You could post the answer and mark it as answered so that it might others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it.

Even though i had set the bitcode to NO it didn't work.

what i did was go to the pods and select the pod that doesn't work with bitcode and changed only that pod to NO on bitcode.

See picture below...[image]